# Creating an has_many relationship through a recursive has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

Situation:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups #<-- recursive sub-groups
  has_many :profiles, through: :groups #<-- This only returns the :profiles of the first groups layer
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company, optional: true
  belongs_to :group, optional: true
  validate :company_xor_group
  has_many :groups
  has_many :profiles
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
end
```

Example data:

```
  company = Company.new
  group = Group.new.profiles.build(name: 'A')
  sub_group = Group.new.profiles.build([{name: 'B'},{name: 'C'}])
  group.groups << sub_group
  company.groups << group
```

So a company has a group, which contains a profile and a sub-group, which contains 2 profiles.

So I want to get *all profiles of a the company*. Currently, the `has_many :profiles, through: :groups` relation, only returns the profiles of the first child group:

```
  company.profiles.length # 1
```

I'm looking for a solution where an ActiveRecord AssociationProxy is returned. I've tried the following:

```
# Company Model
def all_profiles
  groups.map(&:all_profiles)
end

# Group Model
def all_profiles
  profiles + groups.map(&:all_profiles)
end
```

But this returns an array, instead of an `AssociationProxy`.

Comment: Loading nested records with one query is not easily possible with ActiveRecord out of the box and it is not even possible with simple SQL queries. Trying to do so would always end up with recursively call to the database or complex joins in SQL and will therefore have a low performance the deeper the nesting is. But this issue can be solved by using an optimized database schema for this kind of problem. I suggest having a look at gems like [Awesome Nested Set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set)

Comment: I don't know if it's the best solution but I would do 2 steps: first get all the group ids for a Company (doing something like what you already have) and then make a query to get all the profiles `where(group_id: group_ids)`. That will return an ActiveReccord association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @spickermann responded, a huge help with recursive tables is [Awesome Nested Set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set).

The answer to my question "*how can I get it to return an ActiveRecord AssociationProxy?*" was given by @arieljuod:

```
# Company Model
def all_profiles
  Profile.where(group_id: groups.map(&:all_groups).flatten.map(&:id))
end

# Group Model
def all_groups
  [self].push(groups.map(&:all_groups)).flatten.compact
end
```

In my solution this is still quite efficient, because the recursive groups are preloaded. So the `all_groups` method doesn't trigger any new queries.